# Flutter: Not able to run the app on simulator - gradle error

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, simulator

I am trying to run the default app which comes when creating a flutter file using "flutter run" but it gives me the following error:[The error I am facing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyhK7.png)
I did try installing gradle, creating a settings.gradle file in my root directory of project and run "gradle wrapper" it was successful but I still face the same error.

UPDATE: One of my parent directories had spaces in the directory name. After removing the spaces it solved the issue.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow.  Might you please [edit] your question to include your errors and code as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's policy here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.  You're most likely to get an answer if you include a full [mcve] *as text* showing exactly how to reproduce the issue.  See: [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any invalid characters like spaces, etc in any of the parent directory names.

Answer (score 0):

Your `gradle-wrapper` is missing. Make sure that you've a gradle distribution added in your `PATH` variable and restore the wrapper by running this command:

```
gradle wrapper
```